# display date in loops angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to display date,month and year in dropdown list in angularjs.
But i cant find a solution

Here is my code

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<label>Select date</label>
<select ng-model="date">
 <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
 <label>Select month</label>
<select ng-model="month">
 <option value="12">12</option>
</select>
<label>Select year</label>
<select ng-model="year">
 <option value="2015">2015</option>
</select>
```

I want to display the above three drpodowns in a `ng-repeat` to show the date 
ranges from 12-12-1990 to 12-12-2020
How can i do that?

Comment: You can use angular-datetime(https://github.com/eight04/angular-datetime)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by defining a range for the different elements of a date (31 days, 12 months and years from 1900 to 2015), but I would not suggest doing that.

You can never ensure that the values are valid. 
What about 28th february, 29th, 30th?

Use a datepicker, its a much better experience for the user, too.

Answer (score 0):

is this what you're trying to achieve?

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.date = '12';
    $scope.month = '12';
    $scope.year = '1990';

    $scope.getYearRange = function(start, end) {
      // create empty array
      var range = new Array(end - start + 1);

      // fill the array
      angular.forEach(range, function(item, index) {
        range[index] = start + index;
      });

      return range;
    };
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>


<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <label>Select date</label>
  <select ng-model="date">
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select month</label>
  <select ng-model="month">
    <option value="12">12</option>
  </select>
  <label>Select year</label>
  <select ng-model="year">
    <option value="{{year}}" ng-repeat="year in getYearRange(1990, 2020)">{{year}}</option>
  </select>
```

if you want something more complex which usually called datepicker, i think you should use [ui-bootstrap datepicker](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/datepicker)